Cloud Build step cannot reach Docker created via Docker-Compose
I have a docker-compose.yml file that looks like this:
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: <MY_MONGO_IMAGE>
    container_name: mongodb
    hostname: mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: newsie
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/replicaset:/rs0-0
      - ./mongo/init-mongo.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.sh:ro
      - ./mongo/product-collection.json:/product-collection.json:ro
      - ./mongo/org-collection.json:/org-collection.json:ro
      - ./mongo/page-collection.json:/page-collection.json:ro
      - ./mongo/productHierarchy-collection.json:/productHierarchy-collection.json:ro
  api:
    container_name: api
    hostname: api
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=e2e-test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8125:8125"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: cloudbuild

And two steps in Cloud Build that look like this:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: 'Start App'
    args: ['compose', 'up', "-d"]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: 'test backend health endpoint'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-eEuo'
      - 'pipefail'
      - '-c'
      - |-
        sleep 20
        docker logs api
        curl --fail http://workspace-api:8080/health

The docker logs api step successfully gets the startup logs for my API:
2024-05-23 20:37:40.630  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.myapp.api.NewsieApiKt     : Started NewsieApiKt in 7.561 seconds (JVM running for 8.152)

But the curl returns this:
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 502 Cannot find server.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be failing? I want to be able to hit the api from a separate step.

Have you checked this guide first on docker-compose as you may have missed some steps or a new version was already built?
